# THREE.js: Calculate world space position of a point on an object

Tags: rotation, geometry, translation, three.js, webgl

I have a 3D object. "Attached" to it is a point. When the object is moved or rotated, the point moves and rotates with it.

Given the object's position and rotation, how can the position of the point in world space be calculated? (Using [THREE.js's API](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/55) if possible)

Thanks

Comment: Leaving a note here in case it helps others. The marked answer didn't operate as I expected (this is probably a me issue). But I eventually found what I thought it was asking for - ie, the ".getWorldPosition" method.  Ref here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098479/how-to-get-the-global-world-position-of-a-child-object

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For a point in an object's local coordinate system,

```
object.localToWorld( point );
```

will return the world coordinates of the point, assuming the same transform is applied to the point as is applied to the object.

three.js r.55