# Three.js : Absolute coordinates of point on surface

Tags: three.js

I have an object that is rotating. I need to get the world co-ordinates of a point on the surface of the object, and use it for certain calculations. How can I do this easily with Three.js?

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860918/three-js-calculate-world-space-position-of-a-point-on-an-object

Comment: Thanks - That worked.